# How do you test react modal with a filepond?

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am doing testing on react modal that use filepond for a file upload. During upload, there is a load spinner that runs, if loading fails,you get error message. My challenge is doing testing if the modal is working in response to filepond success and failure. How do you do such kind of a testing with react testing library?

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? Your component display different modals on different condition? Or server response with success and error on different condition? Is it E2E testing or functional testing?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want the component to display different modal on a different condition. It is more of E2E testing.

Comment: Maybe test the class names or data attributes in side FilePond? I believe each file item in the files list has a state attribute that reflects the current state.